# Double-critical graph conjecture

Tags: graph-theory

I am confused by extant approaches to proving special cases of the double-critical graph conjecture. Definition:
"A connected, simple graph $G$ is called double-critical, if removing any pair, $(x,y)$, of adjacent vertices lowers the chromatic number by two."
From this definition it is conjectured that the only double-critical graph is the complete graph, $K_k$.
This has been proven for special cases, for example, for $G$ where $\chi(G)=5$ in M. Stiebitz, Discrete Math. 64 (1987)

What is remarkable to me is that the various proof approaches seem needlessly restrictive. For example I never see the steps of $G-x-y$ separated by first removing $x$ from the graph, taking stock, then removing $y$. An obvious starting proposition would be that $H=G-x$ has $\chi(H)=k-1$ and $H$ is also critical. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome you mathematics stack exchange!!!

Comment: I haven't seen these proof approaches, but is there a nice characterization of critical graphs that would help if we removed one vertex at a time? Also it is not obvious that H should be critical because after removing $x$, the vertex $y$ is not arbitrary but a neighbor of $x$.

Comment: Thanks, @Aravind I was missing your observation, that that criticality can't be assumed since $y$ must be a neighbor of $x$. If it could be established that $H$ was critical, then the proof would be trivial--since both $x$ and $y$ would each be sole members of two color classes, just reassign $y$ to a vertex not adjacent to $x$ to be the other sole member of a color class (allows $x$ to be recolored). And if no non-adjacent vertex exists, then $G$ must be $K_k$.